# How to match by row name containing certain character and divide column values across two dataframes?

Tags: r

The following is a sample example of the two data frames

```
> print(df1)
                 A  B
84-9-S04.xlsx   198 15
84-12-S01.xlsx  188 19
92-15-S02.xlsx  157 71
84-12-S08.xlsx  138 51
92-12-S01.xlsx  149 19
84-15-S09.xlsx  138 61
92-15-S02.xlsx  158 14
84-12-S08.xlsx  136 23
92-12-S01.xlsx  124 18
84-9-S09.xlsx   113 14

> print(df2)
       D
84-9   2
84-12  3
84-15  2
92-9   5
92-12  7
84-15  2
```

The first two terms of the row names in df1 are in common with the row names in df2 (e.g. "84-9", "92-15"). I would like to divide all the rows in df1 that contain the same row name as in df2 by df2.

Finally, I would like to separate the data into multiple data frames such that the new data frames by the first two terms of the row names. Meaning one data frame containing all rows that start with "84-9", another data frame containing all rows that start with "92-15"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using `dplyr`. Get the row names as separate column, extract only the relevant information from the column, `left_join` with `df2` and divide the data by `D`.

```
library(dplyr)

total_df <- df1 %>%
  rownames_to_column('file') %>%
  mutate(file1 = sub('(\\d+-\\d+).*', '\\1', file)) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>%
              rownames_to_column('file1'), by = 'file1') %>%
  mutate_at(vars(A, B), ~./D)
```

If we want data in separate dataframes, we can `split` the data and use `list2env`.

```
list_df <- split(total_df, total_df$file)
names(list_df) <- paste0('df_', names(list_df))
list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I would like the total_df data frame to have the same row names as df1 so I can tell which original naming convention they belong to (the S00 part).

Comment: @MaralDorri You cannot have duplicate rownames in dataframe but you can keep it as separate column. I have updated the answer to do that.